# What's the most current, good practice, and easiest way to use sessions in PHP?

Tags: php, session

Sessions in PHP seemed to have changed since the last time I used them, so I'm looking for a simple way of using sessions but at the same time for it to be relatively secure and a good common practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session management changed some time back (I think it was around 4.4). The old mechanism still works, but is deprecated. It's rather confusing, so I recommend staying clear of it. Today, you use sessions by accessing the global variable $_SESSION (It's an array). You *can* put object instances in there, but you need to load the class definitions for those objects before starting the session on the next page. Using [autoload](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) can help you out here.

You must [start a session](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before you can use $_SESSION. Since starting the session sends headers, you can't have any output before. This can be solved in one of two ways:
Either you always begin the session at the start of your script. Or you [buffer all output](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), and send it out at the end of the script.

> One good idea is to regenerate the session on each request. this makes hijack much less likely.

That's (slightly) bad advice, since it can make the site inaccessible. You should [regenerate the session-id](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) whenever a users privileges changes though. In general that means, whenever they log in. This is to prevent session-fixation (A form of session-hijacking). See [this recent thread @ Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=571084) for more on the subject.

Using cookiebased sessions *only* is OK, but if you regenerate session id's on login, it doesn't add any additional security, and it lowers accessibility a bit.

Comment: I have gone over to that sitepoint forum and taken a look. from what I can see they actually seem to recommend id regeneration as well as using cookie only overall.

Comment: Look closely. Regenerate session-id's yes, but *only* when you need to. That means when the user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

As far as simplicity, it doesn't get any better than:

```
# Start the session manager
session_start(); 

# Set a var
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'whatever';

# Access the var
print $_SESSION['foo'];
```

Answer (score 1):

While database might be more secure for sessions, you should focus on what you're storing in the session in the first place - it should not really contain anything but an ID to identify the user (and MAYBE a firstname or a temporary variable between pages).

I would suggest simply using the default, cookies. Database sessions give an extra hit ON EVERY PAGE, and even though not every site is slashdot, there's no harm in pre-optimizing something as simple as this.

For usage, I would recommend the standard global variable:

```
$_SESSION['yourvar'] = 'somevalue';
```

If you use that method in all your code, you can easily change the back-end later through the use of [session_set_save_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php), which gives a unified way of implementing session backends. Note that you can use an object to contain all the session handling, simply give arrays to each entry - array('Staticclass', 'staticmethod').

For more in-depth usage, I would recommend you take a look at how sessions are handled in [KohanaPHP](http://www.kohanaphp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can store PHP sessions in database, as described in [this](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-PHP5.productCd-0764572822.html)
  book. I have used this method and I find it secure and easy to implement, so I would reccomend it.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the $SESSION array in a Session() Object that allows you to get variables from session, get, and post with a similar (yet dissociable) way, including automatic security filters, flash variables (var that are used once then distroyed), and default value setters.

Have a look to the behaviour of Symfony on that point, it´s very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions were a critical part of my PHP Knowledge because it helped me solve my log in authentication problem back when I was developing my first web application.

```
session_start();
if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
{
    if( auth($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) )
    {
        //Authentication passed
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
        // redirect to required page
        header( "Location: index.php" );
    } 
    else 
    {
       //Authentication failed redirect to login
       header( "Location: loginform.html" );
    }
} 
else 
{
      //Username and Password are required
      header( "Location: loginform.html" );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, use cookie based only unless you have a very specific good business reason not to. I had a client that insisted on url based sessions only for a project. very insecure and a pain to work with.

One good idea is to regenerate the session on each request. this makes hijack much less likely. For example.

```
session_start();
$old_sessionid = session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
$new_sessionid = session_id();
```

Another thing that is good practice is if you are doing some kind of user login as part of the system, completely invalidate and empty the session data on a logout to insure that the user is truly logged out of the system. I have seen systems where logout is just accomplished by removing the session cookie.